# Angular .config to typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I m trying to convert this configuration which is written in javascript in my typescript class.

```
.config(function ($provide) {

        $provide.decorator('$rootScope', function ($delegate, $injector) {
            $delegate.getRequireService = function () {
                return $injector.get('requireService');
            };
            $delegate.getTrackingService = function () {
                return $injector.get('trackingService');
            };
            return $delegate;
        });
    }
        );
```

i made the services which is used here as functions like trackingService =>  public getTrackingApi() or requireService => public require().
But i dont know how to convert this .config which is written in javascript to typescript with same functionality.. (Basically i made services of a module as inside of a class just methods.)
Any help would be greatly appriciated !

what i dis so far :

```
angular.module('tracking.TrackingSrv', [])
            .service('TrackingSrv', tracking.TrackingSrv);
            .config(function ($provide) {

                $provide.decorator('$rootScope', function ($delegate, $injector) {
                    $delegate.getRequireService = function () {
                        return $injector.get('requireService');
                    };
                    $delegate.getTrackingService = function () {
                        return $injector.get('trackingService');
                    };
                    return $delegate;
                });
            }
```

but doesnt work. i dont know what to write for  $injector.get('requireService') in type script. I turned requireService as a single method in a class